# Verification of convergence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a series of random variables with:

$$P(X_n = 2^n) = \frac{1}{2^n} \hspace{15pt}\text{and}\hspace{15pt} P(X_n = 0) = 1-\frac{1}{2^n}$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

*Question*: Does a random variable $Z$ exist with $X_n \rightarrow Z$ (in distribution), $X_n \rightarrow Z$ (in probability), $X_n \rightarrow Z$ (in $\mathcal{L}_2)$?

*(my) Solution*: I saw that $X_n \rightarrow 0$ (in probability) and proved it. For $\epsilon > 0$ we get:

$$P(|X_n - 0| > \epsilon) = P(|X_n| > \epsilon) \leq P(|X_n| \neq 0) \\ = 1 - P(|X_n| = 0) = \frac{1}{2^n} \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$$
Now this already implies that $X_n \rightarrow 0$ (in distribution) and that if there exists a random variable $Z$ with $X_n \rightarrow Z$ (in $\mathcal{L}_2)$ $Z \equiv 0$. I proceeded by testing:

$$||X_n - Z||_{\mathcal{L_2}}^2 = E(|X_n|^2) = (2^n)^2\cdot\frac{1}{2^n} + 0\cdot (1 - \frac{1}{2^n}) = 2^n \neq 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$$

And concluded that $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge in $\mathcal{L}_2$.

Is this argumentation correct? Is there a way to approach problems like this more efficiently (I just *thought* that $X_n \rightarrow 0$ (in probability) and tested it)?

Comment: Isn't $EX_n^2=2^n$?  Otherwise, it all looks good to me.  (You can use Borel Cantelli to get a.s. convergence to 0, as well.)

Comment: @kimchilover You are right! It forgot to square the $2^n$. But how can I use Borel Cantelli? Id the happy to accept your comment (with some more explanation on the usage of Borel Cantelli to show a.s. convergence) as an answer!

Comment: Edit your post to fix the typo.  As for BC: since $\sum P(X_n\ne0)<\infty$, with probability 1 only finitely many of the events $X_n\ne1$ occur, that is, $X_n$ is, with probability, ultimately 0.  Said another way: the rv. $S=\sum_n X_n$ has finite expectation, so it is finite with probability 1.

Comment: @kimchilover The typo is fixed, but I can't exactly follow (I'm quite new to the subject). I understand that using BC: I can conclude $P(\lim\sup_{n\rightarrow\infty} |X_n|) = 0$, but how does the a.s. convergence follow at this point? I need to show that $P(\{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}X_n \text{ exists}\}) = 1$ to conclude a.s. convergence.

Comment: I said $S$ has finite expectation, but that of course is wrong.  I meant, $EN<\infty$ where $N$ is the number of $n$ such that $X_n\ne0$.  As for the BC stuff: whenever $N$ is finite, then for all $n$ sufficiently large, $X_n = 0$, which implies $\lim X_n = 0$.  But $N$ is finite with probability 1.

Answer (score 1):

I agree for the reasoning for the convergence in probability.

For the $\mathbb L^2$-convergence, you used implicitely the fact that if a sequence converges in $\mathbb L^2$ to $Z$ and in probability to $Z'$ then $Z=Z'$ almost surely, which is true. It rests on the fact that convergence in $\mathbb L^2$ implies convergence in probability.

As pointed out in the comment, the sequence $\left(X_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is also convergent to $0$ almost surely. To see this, one case use the Borel-Cantelli lemma with $A_n:=\{X_n\neq 0\}$.